# Multi-page wizard in MVC - where to store the entered data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wizard

What do you think it's the best way to create a wizard over several pages in asp.net-mvc ?
I am thinking to:

1. create a hidden field in every page
   which contain my whole object
   serialized
2. override OnActionExecuting -> get my
   object from the hidden or tempdata
3. override OnResultExecuted -> put the
   object in tempdata, when i go to the
   next page(when redirect)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Wrap each step in the wizard in some `<form>` element
2. Do a form submit when going to the next step (either through javascript or via `<input type='submit'>`
3. Handle the form-post to extract the data inserted by the user
4. Store your previously stored answers in a `Session` variable, and retrieve the object when in the form-post
5. Add the new answers, and re-save the object in `Session`
6. When finishing, retrieve the object, and persist the settings.

Just have some

```
[Serializable]
public class WizardAnswers
```

which contains properties for each wizard-answer to save the user's data in.